# $\int_S \boldsymbol F\cdot d\boldsymbol S $ Creates contradiction with Divergence Thm?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I am given that my surface S is given by;

$$ S = (\boldsymbol x : |\boldsymbol x|=1) $$
$$\boldsymbol F(\boldsymbol x)=\boldsymbol x/r^3  $$
Compute  $$\int_S  \boldsymbol F\cdot d\boldsymbol S $$

My Approach,

I use spherical polars and get that $$d\boldsymbol S = sin(\theta) \boldsymbol e_r d\theta d\phi $$
and thus I calculate $$\int_S  \boldsymbol F\cdot d\boldsymbol S = \int_{\phi =0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^\pi sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi=4\pi$$

However Gauss' Thm gives
$$\int_S  \boldsymbol F\cdot d\boldsymbol S = \int_V \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol FdV  $$
but $$\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol F = 0$$ Which contradicts my above result? Im wondering if I have made a mistake in the computation of my first integral or maybe Divergence Thm doesnt hold because F is undefined at the origin?

EDIT:
I think I realise now that the integral over the volume of the divergence is not 0 and instead given by,

$$ \int_V \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol FdV =  \int_{\phi =0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^\pi \int_0^1 \delta(r)sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi =4\pi $$
And i Think this is correct and thus divergence thm still holds?

Comment: The naive form of divergence theorem doesn't apply precisely for the reason mentioned in your last sentence. The usual statement requires quite strong assumptions like $\mathbf{F}$ being $C^1$ on its domain of definition and that the region of integration be contained in that domain of definition. This is not a contradiction at all: you just cannot apply the divergence theorem in this situation (unless you prove a more general version of the theorem allowing for distributions etc).

Comment: Thank you, This was what I suspected however i was just unsure as to whether I had made an error or Divergence thm doesnt hold.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your notations well. But if you take example of a vector field $\vec F = \frac{\hat \rho}{\rho^2}$ and region as a sphere of radius $R$, the surface integral calculates the flux as $4 \pi$. Do you see something interesting here? Regardless of the radius of the sphere, the flux is $4\pi$.

Comment: When it comes to divergence, you can easily see that divergence is zero for $\rho \ne 0$ and in fact this vector field has divergence only at the origin but we cannot calculate because $\vec F$ blows up at the origin. If you read about Dirac Delta function, you will see that the whole contribution to the flux is coming from the point $\rho = 0$.

Comment: Hello, I was just confused as I thought if I calculaate the integral over the volume for the divergence it would = 0 , but perhaps I am mistaken? I am aware of the dirac delta function however have not properly studied it yet and thus maybe that gives the integral over the volume of the divergence to be 4pi and then divergence thm holds?

Comment: I have made an edit to my post to show what Im thinking, and i believe this is correct?

Comment: $$\nabla\cdot\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}=4\pi \delta ^3(\vec{r}), \int_{\Omega}\delta^3({\vec{r}})d^3x=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\delta(r)\delta(\theta)\delta(\phi)}{r^2sin(\theta)}r^2sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi=1$$ (Abit irrelevant but does Cambridge teach VC in lent term?)

Comment: Yeah I am currently studying VC, I see my integral is wrong in the bottom of the question. How do u get the divergence out to be $\nabla \cdot \frac {\boldsymbol r} {r^3} = 4\pi \delta ^3 (\boldsymbol r) $

Comment: If it was $\delta(r)$ instead, $\int_{V}\nabla \cdot F dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^14\pi\delta(r)r^2sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi=0 \neq 4\pi$ as $\int_0^1\delta(r)r^2dr=0$. The 3D Dirac Delta is defined as $\delta^3(\vec{r})=\frac{\delta(x^1)\delta(x^2)\delta(x^3)}{h_1h_2h_3}$ where $h_i$ are the scale factors of the curvilinear coordiantes $x^1,x^2,x^3$, which prevent $0$ from being generated. 
(I see... it was once my dream to read the maths tripos there but was not smart enough to be admitted, ended up as a 1st year physicist instead...).

Comment: Oh i see, that makes sense thanks =P ahh natsci seems very hard aha